# How to make Google's SpeechClient.StreamingRecognize.WriteAsync faster?

Tags: asynchronous, google-cloud-platform, webservice-client

Google's Cloud Speech-To-Text API is incredible, but for some reason it takes around 90 seconds to complete the WriteAsync() call before anything further happens.

I'm using the C# code, unaltered, right off of GitHub (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/api/Recognize/Recognize.cs). When I invoke any of the methods (StreamingMicRecognizeAsync, SyncRecognizeWithCredentials, etc.) it works as expected except for this huge delay. I don't see anything wrong anywhere, no exceptions being thrown or anything, it just takes forever to get past this code:

```
var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
var streamingCall = speech.StreamingRecognize();
// Write the initial request with the config.
await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
    new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
    {
        StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
        {
            Config = new RecognitionConfig()
            {
                Encoding =
                RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                LanguageCode = "en",
            },
            InterimResults = true,
        }
    });
```

This isn't that much of a problem with files, but waiting 90 seconds before being able to speak into a microphone is not a good scenario for our potential customers! :)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: There shouldn't be a 90 second wait time for that, Can you provide the guide that you are using to get a better view on your setup?

Comment: Thanks for responding Alex. I download the project from GitHub (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api) and built it in Visual Studio 2015. The only other thing I had to do was sign up for a Google Cloud trial account, enable the Speech API, acquire a credential JSON file, and point the sample to that file. If that part hadn't worked, I think that instead of a delay I'd either get an exception or an infinite wait, but it works just fine after the delay. No other web services I consume have latency like this. Does Google deprioritize trial accounts?